# common function in base and derived calling base when called through another base function using a derived object?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class dissection {
  int x;
  public:
    void test() {
     cout<<"Test base";
   }
    void caller(){ test(); }
};

class dissectionDerived: public dissection {
  int x;
  public:
    void  test(){ 
    cout<< "Test derived";  
    }
};

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
  dissectionDerived derived;
  derived.caller();
  return 0;
}
```

In the code sample above, the ouput is "**Test base**". The way I was thought about it was, since derived doesn’t have a function named **caller** it could  invoke the base class function, however since the actual type of the object is **dissectionDerived** it would be able to call test function of  dissectionDerived  class. Is this because overload resolution stops after it finds the closest test function in the base class scope?

If the **caller** function can be invoked from the derived function, why cant it also be a part of the overload resolution in the derived class ?

I have used -cg g++ compiler flag and then did an obj dump of the objectfile, the output is shown below:

```
SYMBOL TABLE:

0000000000000000 l    d  .text._ZN10dissection4testEv   0000000000000000 .text._ZN10dissection4testEv
0000000000000000 l    d  .text._ZN10dissection6callerEv 0000000000000000 .text._ZN10dissection6callerEv
0000000000000000  w    F .text._ZN10dissection4testEv   000000000000001d _ZN10dissection4testEv
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 __gxx_personality_v0
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 _ZSt4cout
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
0000000000000000  w    F .text._ZN10dissection6callerEv 000000000000001a _ZN10dissection6callerEv
```

c++filt _ZN10dissection4testEv gives dissection::test()

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you want "which actual class is involved" to determine which function gets called, that function needs to be marked `virtual`.

This makes the compiler put a "virtual function table" as part of that and any derived class.

In other words, make `virtual void test();` in `base`. The `virtual` attribute will "inherit", so your derived class will also be `virtual` - for "safety" you can mark it `override` (e.g. `void test() override { ... }`, to ensure that the compiler gives an error if you try to "override" something that isn't part of the base-class.

Answer (score 1):

For historical reasons the default dispatch in C++ is logically **wrong** i.e. depends on the static type of the reference/pointer and not on the actual type of the object.

> With "static type" in C++ what is meant is the type of the reference or of the pointer... i.e. in `const BaseObj& x;` the static type of `x` is `BaseObj`.
>
> With "dynamic type" it's meant instead the real type of the object instance beging pointed to or referenced and can be either the same as the static type or a type derived from it. For example in `BaseObj *p = new DerivedObj;` the static and dyamic types are different.
>
> With non-virtual methods (unfortunately the default) the code called **depends on the static type and not on the real type of the instance**.
>
> The official reason for this logically wrong default is efficiency so the address to call can be computed at link time and is fixed.

To have the dispatch depending on the type of the object you need to declare the member function to be `virtual`.
Note that the `virtual` keyword is needed per method but only in the base class as in that case it's assumed also in all derived classes... it's anyway IMO good documentation to repeat it also in derived classes.

Also remember that in C++ it's very important to declare the destructor virtual for classes that are meant to be derived and destroyed polymorphically because even for it otherwise you're going to run into trouble (undefined behavior) if deleting a derived instance using a `delete` on a pointer to a base.

Normally in a C++ program either a class is not meant to be derived (then the `virtual` keyword is not present and you can shave off a few bytes from each instance) or it's meant to be derived and it's better to declare the destructor and other methods to be `virtual`. Having a non-virtual method in a class meant to be derived is sort of an exception and IMO should happen only for proven good reasons.

[In the words of C++ original author](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#virtual) the non-virtual dispatch by default was just because of classes not meant to be used as bases and because of memory optimization and byte level compatibility with C and Fortran structures.

Comment: why the bias?   It's not in itself "good" or "wrong". It is just a different thing respect to what you want.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: what is wrong is that it's the default... having a `nonvirtual` dispatch for performance reasons would have been much better from a language point of view.

Comment: May be I''m limited, but I'm completely unable to see any conceptual difference.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: If I write a method specialization for a derived class it's quite surprising that it doesn't get called and this is exactly what surprised the OP. Of course you can implement anything using either default-as-virtual or default-as-non-virtual... the point is what is the least surprising. This is not a major wart of C++ (there are much worse around), but for sure it is one.

Comment: Thank you for your response, correct me if I am wrong, the static type of dissectionDerived is dissectionDerived( as we are using the object itself and not a pointer or reference of the base type) right?  Shouldn't the behaviour be different with pointers/references and objects.

Comment: @deb: I've added an explanation of what is meant in C++ with "static type" and "dynamic type"

Comment: *"Also remember that in C++ it's very important to declare the destructor virtual for classes that are meant to be derived"* - That's only true for classes which are used polymorphically. Think of classes like `std::input_iterator_tag`. They do not have virtual destructors.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: actually it's formally needed only if **destroying** them polymorphically... added the wording. Note that if the class has any virtual method however there is no real reason for not declaring the destructor virtual too (you already paid the price for a VMT, and if the exact type is known at compile time the VMT won't be used anyway).

Comment: @6502: That's true. I have never seen a use case for class with virtual functions but no virtual destructor. As far as I am concerned, the language may as well make the destructor implicitly virtual if any virtual function is present. But perhaps there are such exotic edge cases.

Comment: Don't confuse c++ inheritance with OOP substitution. C++ inheritance is just a composition mechanism (anonymous membership). C++ is not an OOP-only language. OOP substitution paradigm in C++ requires public inheritance AND virtual methods (and the destructor in this sense is not special). C++ generic functional programming don't (and use inheritance to define priority sequences). If you programming style if mostly about OOP, you fill uncomfortable. If it is not just that, than having composition mechanisms separated from dispatching mechanisms helps.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: the non-virtual dispatch is meant for classes not used as base and it's an optimization and memory-layout-compatibility trick. You are of course free to create rationalizations that make this choice the logical choice instead of the hack it really is... but it's just in your mind (or at least it's not in the mind of who actually created the language... see http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#virtual).

Comment: "the non-virtual dispatch is meant for classes not used as base". CRTP has base classes without virtual dispatch. And it's not the only paradigm the do without it. Lot of meta-programming uses inheritance to reuse behaviors,  not to specify abstract interfaces.  Stroustrup was just giving an example, and I'm not that sure about you vulcan mind meld capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

To print "Test derived", declare `dissection::test()` as `virtual`:

```
virtual void test(){ cout<<"Test base"; }
```

Comment: I would upvote if you threw in an explanation for why that is

Comment: It is `test()` that has to be virtual, not `caller()`.